# Arch linux won't boot: error: no such device

Tags: arch-linux, boot, system-installation

I've been following an unofficial arch install tutorial, and I've done everything as shown, but upon booting I get this:

[image: error: no such device: ad4103fa-d940-47ca-9506-301d8071d467]

Can I fix this? How? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out: I forgot to run `grub-mkconfig`.